# pandoc command param --epub-cover-image generate fail

Tags: pandoc

I wanna generate docx from markdown files ,and insert into the conver picture, From [pandoc metada](http://www.pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#epub-metadata) , I can use --epub-cover-image.

My directory :

[image]

then command:

```
pandoc -s a.md b.md c.md -o example.docx --epub-cover-image cover.png
```

It generate example.docx file, but the cover.png does not insert into the docx file ?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the pandoc [manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) section on `--epub-cover-image`:

> Use the specified image as the EPUB cover.

Since you are not generating a EPUB ebook but a docx word file, the option has simply no effect.

Comment: Do you know how to generate cover-image ?